# How can we post data on server and then in response get NSData using Afnetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:@"39.6994090" forKey:@"latitude"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"url" parameters:parameters];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: You need to ask a question. This is just code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the AFNetworking GitHub and Docs, they're really good.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"latitude": @"39.6994090" };
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```